# Does Data ever learn to sneeze?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

In the TNG episode *Datalore*, it begins with Data trying to emulate sneezing.  That got me thinking - does Data ever learn to actually sneeze?

Comment: Given that he doesn't actually need to do it....I would speculate, no. Perhaps by the events of the future timeline in "All Good Things", he might have learned to mimic it, but by that time (really, much before that time) he'd have realized its lack of worth. Sneezing was an experiment in humanity for Data - one of many. I speculate it was one of the failed ones.

Comment: In Campbell's "Brain Stealers of Mars" (an early version of his "Who Goes There?" on which *The Thing* movies were based), the almost-perfect imitators were unmasked by their inability to sneeze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes in the expanded Universe (Star Trek: The Next Generation: Cold Equations series) Data receives all the memories and abilities of his Father Noonien Soong.

Comment: Is sneezing actually mentioned?  It's a function of physiology, not memories, so I wouldn't think it was..

Comment: @Izkata well the method by which data is *born again* is a complete encapsulation of his father memories and abilities.

Comment: Plus he already has the memories of various colonists and that doesn't seem to help him.

Comment: @Richard rather than simply having the memories his father's entire "soul" is the foundation of his programming now.

Comment: @Richard In "Silicon Avatar," Data states that "The contents of their logs and journals were transferred into my memory cells." This would not help him sneeze.

Comment: @jpmc26 - Datalore suggests that Soong was experimenting with memory transfer. This data was included on the emotion chip. It may also have been what sent Lore insane.

Comment: @Richard I'm not familiar with that, but when you said, "already has the memories of various colonists", I interpreted that to mean you were saying he always had them. The emotion chip certainly wouldn't be a factor in the scene the OP is referring to since it wasn't installed during the series. Did you mean something else by "already"? (And I think a better basis for Soong working on memory transfer technology would be Juliana from "Inheritance".)

Comment: @jpmc26 - Yes. Also Ira Graves was working on the same lines. I always assumed that Data had similar engrammatic programming although I can't place the specific quote.